# Python: Why donnot I get a result in the terminal

Tags: python

Python: Why don't I get a result in the terminal

```
def is_even(number):
      if number % 2 == 0:
        return True
      return False
    
is_even(10)
```

Comment: you forgot to `print` what the function returns, also you can shorten the function to `return number % 2 == 0`

Answer (score 1):

You need to print the output of the function. You also need to create the function.

```py
def is_even(num):
   if num % 2 == 0:
      return True
   else:
      return False

print(is_even(10)) #True
print(is_even(7))  #False
```

Comment: why did you add the `else` clause, it's not even in the question (as in it's not there because it's unnecessary yet you added it)

Comment: @Matiiss It's more clear, and I wrote my answer before he added his code to the question.

Comment: it's not more clear, it's absolutely unnecessary, in fact the entire `if` statement is unnecessary, you can just `return num % 2 == 0`

Comment: @Matiiss I mean yeah, you don't need it, but you don't always have to write the fewest number of lines to have a good solution. I like my code to be more readable, so anyone can understand it. It's a preference.